# iOS App crashes after one click

Tags: ios, swift

My iOS app crashes as soon as I press something. As soon as I press the password textbox or anything else it crashes. Code below:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class SecondRegisterViewController: UIViewController {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    @IBOutlet weak var UsernameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var PasswordText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ConfirmText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var FirstNameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var MiddleNameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var LastNameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var EmailText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var NextButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func NextButton(_ sender: Any) {
        ref?.child("Usernames").childByAutoId().setValue(UsernameText.text)
        ref?.child("Passwords").childByAutoId().setValue(PasswordText.text)
        ref?.child("First Names").childByAutoId().setValue(FirstNameText.text)
        ref?.child("Last Names").childByAutoId().setValue(LastNameText.text)
        ref?.child("Middle Names").childByAutoId().setValue(MiddleNameText.text)
        ref?.child("Emails").childByAutoId().setValue(EmailText.text)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = Database.database().reference()
        NextButton.isHidden = false

        if  UsernameText.text?.isEmpty == false && PasswordText.text?.isEmpty == false &&
            ConfirmText.text?.isEmpty == false &&
            FirstNameText.text?.isEmpty == false &&
            MiddleNameText.text?.isEmpty == false &&
            LastNameText.text?.isEmpty == false &&
            EmailText.text?.isEmpty == false{
            NextButton.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

It also says:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with the uncaught exception of type NSException

This is a big problem and I would be grateful for any help.

I fully connected all outlets and full console below:

```
2018-07-29 06:50:33.225228+0530 SchoolDrive[22497:4253058] -[SchoolDrive.SecondRegisterViewController UsernameText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffc57c2e840
2018-07-29 06:50:33.321943+0530 SchoolDrive[22497:4253058] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SchoolDrive.SecondRegisterViewController UsernameText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffc57c2e840'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001036381e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102ccd031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001036b9784 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   UIKit                               0x0000000103ce36db -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 295
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001035ba898 ___forwarding___ + 1432
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001035ba278 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000103ab63e8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000103c317a4 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000103c31ac1 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001047ca2a0 -[UITextField _resignFirstResponder] + 155
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000103ce30c8 -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder] + 286
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001047c9ebf -[UITextField _finishResignFirstResponder] + 48
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000103ce3177 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 140
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001047c9d8f -[UITextField resignFirstResponder] + 135
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000103ce2df0 -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 655
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000103b6cb68 -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 145
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001047c8aff -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 110
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000103dbf389 -[UIKeyboardImpl handleTabWithShift:beforePublicKeyCommands:] + 384
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000103db5cea -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyCommand:repeatOkay:beforePublicKeyCommands:] + 4884
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000103dd26ce -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyEvent:executionContext:] + 1166
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000104832bd3 -[UIKeyboardTaskEntry execute:] + 164
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001048313dd -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread] + 374
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000103dd21af -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyEvent:] + 210
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001035bbccc __invoking___ + 140
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001035bbb84 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 308
    25  UIKit                               0x00000001043f2cad -[UIRepeatedAction invoke] + 293
    26  UIKit                               0x00000001043f2ce3 -[UIRepeatedAction _preInvocationTimerFire] + 22
    27  UIKit                               0x0000000103ad1614 -[UIApplication _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 2050
    28  UIKit                               0x0000000103ce4cdb -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    29  UIKit                               0x0000000103ce4cdb -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    30  UIKit                               0x0000000103ce4cdb -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    31  UIKit                               0x0000000103ce4cdb -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    32  UIKit                               0x0000000103ce4cdb -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    33  UIKit                               0x0000000103ce4cdb -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    34  UIKit                               0x0000000103ce4cdb -[UIResponder _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 79
    35  UIKit                               0x0000000103ad0b3c -[UIApplication handleKeyUIEvent:] + 103
    36  UIKit                               0x0000000103ad0ab5 -[UIApplication handleKeyHIDEvent:] + 692
    37  UIKit                               0x0000000104410fa8 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 997
    38  UIKit                               0x00000001044142c4 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5949
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001035dabb1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001035bf4af __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001035bea6f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001035be30b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
    43  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010988ea73 GSEventRunModal + 62
    44  UIKit                               0x0000000103ab5057 UIApplicationMain + 159
    45  SchoolDrive                         0x0000000100fce117 main + 55
    46  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010679f955 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: You need to post more of the error and you need to point out the exact line of code causing the error. But my guess is that one or more of your outlets isn't connected properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [SchoolDrive.SecondRegisterViewController UsernameText:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x7ffc57c2e840 2018-07-29
>   06:50:33.321943+0530 SchoolDrive[22497:4253058] * **Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[SchoolDrive.SecondRegisterViewController UsernameText:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance** 0x7ffc57c2e840'

When dealing with layouts, an unrecognized selector usually means there's an issue with the way you've connected your IBOutlets. In this case, either you're trying to use a view that you haven't connected yet, or, more likely since you said you've connected all outlets, you connected one twice/where it shouldn't go. Doing either one of those will cause issues.

Try ctrl + clicking on all of your views and seeing what they're connected to - chances are you'll find something wrong.

If everything checks out, try removing all connections and redoing them. If *that* doesn't work, come back and let us know you've ruled that out.

Edit: Since the error message specifies UsernameText, that's probably where the error lies, but it doesn't hurt to check the rest.

Comment: All I had to do was delete te IBOutlts on that screen and re add them. It worked like a charm once I did it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try removing and re-adding the class of your SecondRegisterViewController viewConteoller.

Do the following steps .

1. Select your SecondRegisterViewController from interfaceBuilder.
2. Go to the class selectionTab (left side tab of attribute inspector) .
3. Remove your custom class (SecondRegisterViewController) and hit enter.
4. Again associat your custom class ( SecondRegisterViewController) with the viewController and hit enter.
5. Build and run.